# Print matrix as string in golang

Tags: arrays, string, go

I have a matrix of integers, represented by a multivariate array.  I'm  trying to concatenate the numbers into a string representation, rows-by-columns.  My naive approach is to walk over all entries in the matrix and append them to a nullstring.

However, I'm getting an error that my append function is saying:

```
./main.go:xx:yy: first argument to append must be slice; have string
```

My code is:

```
type MatString string 
type IntMat [3][3]Int // external constraints require fixed size, symmetric.

func Matrix2String(t IntMat) MatString {
    // s var string
    s := ""
    for i := range t {
        for j := range t[i] {
            s = append(s[:], fmt.Sprintf("%s", j))
            // fmt.Sprintf(s)
        }
    }
    return MatString(s)
}
```

What am I misunderstanding about arrays, slices, and joins, and how can I iteratively build up this string correctly?

Comment: Strings are immutable. Just use `s += fmt.Sprintf(....` Which recreates the string. A comment on `strings` and `slices`. Technically a `string` IS a `[]byte`, but it is specifically an _immutable_ structure. Thus, you can't use `append` as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collect the elements in a slice of strings. Join the slice to produce the result.

```
func Matrix2String(t IntMat) MatString {
    var s []string
    for i := range t {
        for _, n := range t[i] {
            s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%d", n))
        }
    }
    return MatString(strings.Join(s, ""))
}
```

Another approach is to build the string in a []byte and convert at the end:

```
func Matrix2String(t IntMat) MatString {
    var s []byte
    for i := range t {
        for _, n := range t[i] {
            s = strconv.AppendInt(s, int64(n), 10)
        }
    }
    return MatString(s)
}
```

I didn't include any delimiters because the question didn't include them.

Comment: This is better than my comment

Comment: Got it, there was one other thing that I had to change: `s = append(s, strconv.Itoa(n))`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate converted integers to strings, to the response

```
func Matrix2String(t IntMat) MatString {
    s := ""

   for i := range t {
      for _, n := range t[i] {
          s += fmt.Sprintf("%d", n)
      }
   }

    return MatString(s)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WVK9PC4kEbz)